# Editing contents of a pointer from JNI in Java directly

Tags: java, c, pointers, java-native-interface

I'm working on an application that uses JNI for some processing. I've read a few articles on the topic (including some of the ones on StackOverflow) but haven't found a definite answer - can I return a pointer from JNI and use it like a reference in the Java code?

Basically I have a JNI call that's passing a byte pointer with another application, and what I would like to happen is I can have the byte array allocated in the C code and modify it directly in Java, instead of copying it into a JVM structure, editing it and passing it back.

I've seen it going the other way, or returning pointers to longs and passing them back and forth, and copying memory between structures but none of those are what I want. I basically want my Java application to do some direct memory access to a byte array defined externally.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. You can use com.sun.jna.Memory, which extends Pointer, and use any of the write methods, e.g., Pointer#write(long bOff, byte[] buf, int index, int length), to update its contents.  It's constructor allocates a block of native memory (Memory(long size)).  If you need to read from the structure, you can use any of the various get methods like getByte(long) methods.
2. You can use ByteBuffer#allocateDirect, which JNA will detect and use the native buffer in any calls.

Answer (score 0):

A Java byte array is a managed object. It is impossible to wrap `byte[]` around an arbitrary `unsigned char*`. You can go other way around: allocate a `byte[]` in Java or with JNI function, lock it, and use the pointer arithmetic on the result - until you unlock it. But Java has a more friendly class for that purpose: **DirectByteBuffer**. Its big advantage is that it does not need lock/unlock to go from Java to C and back. Not to be confused with a regular ByteBuffer, which wraps `byte[]`.